# Link list of opportunity records to Custom object

Tags: custom-object, opportunity

I have a custom field in the opportunity object as empID. I have a custom object EmployeeOpportunities where I define the empID , how can I link list of opportunities to this custom object. The reason to link is to get the report access.

Currently I used lookup/ master-detail relationship to link custom object to Opportunity object .However only one opportunity record is able to get linked.

Please advise

Comment: [Editing your question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/151268/edit) to include the information about only having one license for Salesforce would be a good idea. It sounds like that's very important to your question, and any correct answer will need to take this into account.

Comment: What I think I understand so far is that you only have 1 user license in your org (due to cost), and you're trying to add a field to `Opportunity` to track who the 'real' owner is (for reporting purposes, as you indicate). What is the purpose of `EmpolyeeOpportunities`? Is it supposed to hold employee information? Do you want multiple employees to 'own' a single `Opportunity`? Is your relationship field on `Opportunity` or on `EmployeeOpportunities`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you need to match 1 EmployeeOpportunities to several opportunities - usually it's done by **junction object** - would suggest you to google for it.

Also, by the name of the object I could suggest that employeeOpportunities is a person who works on this particular opportunity. If so, you could try to use Opportunity teams standard functional.

Comment: We just have one license and managing the Opportunity owners through a custom field. Not sure if team would work for us .

Comment: @rrmo so, the only option for you is to use junktion object. Can't tell you more since I only read theory about it and never used in a real implementation.